# FontAwesomeIcons add Tooltip

Tags: java, javafx, icons, font-awesome

I downloaded a .jar for FontAwesomeIcons and integrated it into my project. Now I would like to add a tooltip to my icon, unfortunately it will be denied (on labels, button funkoniert it). Does anyone have a solution so that I can also put an icon on a tooltip?

[image]

Comment: You question is a little confusing. Are you trying to add an icon to a tooltip or add a tooltip to your icon?

Comment: If you are trying to install a Tooltip on the FontAwesome icon itself, which eventually inherits from the `Text` class, you can install it by simply calling the static `install()` method of the `Tooltip` class:  `Tooltip.install(icon, new Tooltip("This is a tooltip.");`

Comment: @Zephyr Sorry that my question was too misleading. I have an icon and on this icon I would like to add a tooltip (if I move the mouse over the icon I see a little message over the mouse pointer). Understandable? And thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask two conflicting questions but here is how you could do both.

**Add Image to Tooltip**

The `FontAwesomeIconView` inherits from the `Node` class (eventually) so it can be set as the `graphic` property of your tooltip

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
tooltip.setGraphic(new FontAwesomeIconView());
```

**Add a Tooltip to FontAwesomeIconView**

`FontAwesomeIconView` is a standard `Node` so you can easily install a tooltip on it:

```
Tooltip.install(fontAwesomeIcon, new Tooltip("Click me"));
```

Comment: You don't need the 'mouseOverEvent'. The tool tip handles that. Just install the tool tip somewhere in your 'initialize()' method.